# How to prevent web service from starting if install condition not met on WebSphere Application Server?

Tags: java, web-services, web, ear, websphere-8

We have a web service running on WebSphere Application Server.

When certain critical properties are missing, we want to prevent the EAR containing the web service from starting outright thus preventing more esoteric and complicated errors downstream.

What is the best way to achieve that? We tried throwing runtime errors, they log well, but that does not prevent the application from starting.

Thank you in advance for any help,
Bertrand

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) in order to achieve this. Its an interface for receiving notification events about ServletContext lifecycle changes.

In order to receive these notification events, the implementation class must be either declared in the deployment descriptor of the web application, annotated with WebListener, or registered via one of the addListener methods defined on ServletContext.

Implementations of this interface are invoked at their contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent) method in the order in which they have been declared, and at their contextDestroyed(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent) method in reverse order.